# How to use OpenCV RTrees for binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, opencv3.1

The RTrees API seems to have changed across different versions.  The [RTrees 2.4.1 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html) says that it supports both regression and classification, though I don't see how it's possible to do so.

I want to use RTrees as a binary classifier in OpenCV 3.1, though the documentation doesn't say anything about it and RTrees::isClassifier() returns false.

```
m_pTrees->setMaxDepth(20);
m_pTrees->setMinSampleCount(10);

cv::TermCriteria criteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 0, 0);
m_pTrees->setTermCriteria(criteria);
m_pTrees->setCalculateVarImportance(false);
m_pTrees->setRegressionAccuracy(0);

// I assumed setting categories makes it a classifier.
m_pTrees->setMaxCategories(2);

// Always returns a float (that looks like the average of votes).
// I expected a single 0 or 1 (since max categories is 2).
m_pTrees->predict(sample);
```

EDIT: I've done some more legwork and looked into the OpenCV source code.  `RTrees` creates a hidden implementation of `DTReesImplForRTrees` object which extends the `DTreesImpl` class.  This class manages the `_isClassifier` member variable and sets it according to the response type of the TrainData given to `train()`.

From tree.cpp in OpenCV source code

```
_isClassifier = data->getResponseType() == VAR_CATEGORICAL;
```

At the moment, I don't see any method of configuring the TrainData object to return this.  Perhaps it's because my training classes are stored as floats instead of integers?  If I remember correctly, the data type was required to be CV_32F, but maybe I made an error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question since I found it a little confusing and tough to find any obvious documentation on.  I only understood that the data needed to be considered categorical by looking at the source code for DTreesImpl.

Though I'm not sure if it will make a major difference.  Admittedly I'm very new to ML and OpenCV's implementation of it.

```
/** @brief Creates training data from in-memory arrays.

@param samples matrix of samples. It should have CV_32F type.
@param layout see ml::SampleTypes.
@param responses matrix of responses. If the responses are scalar, they should be stored as a
    single row or as a single column. The matrix should have type CV_32F or CV_32S (in the
    former case the responses are considered as ordered by default; in the latter case - as
    categorical)
 */
CV_WRAP static Ptr<TrainData> create(InputArray samples, int layout, InputArray responses,
                             InputArray varIdx=noArray(), InputArray sampleIdx=noArray(),
                             InputArray sampleWeights=noArray(), InputArray varType=noArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the example ~/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp
It's an example using RTrees for 26 classes (letters). To use it for binary class data, you just need to feed data with 2 class labels (responses in the code)